# Directly creating a new disconnected git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

I have started a project and already have some commits. I would like to change my approach, and commit everything on a clean slate. Is it possible to commit a work tree as an unconnected first commit directly, or do I really need to use a temporary remote for that?

Basically how I know I can do:

```
mkdir BOO
cd BOO
git init
... # create the first and maybe more commits...
cd ..
git remote add boo BOO
git fetch boo
git checkout -b boo/master new-master
git remote delete boo
rm -rf BOO/
```

Do I really need to use a temporary remote definition like above, or **is there a way to directly create an unconnected starting commit**?

(If it is not evident from the question, I would like to keep the original main branch still intact, at least for a while, for verification purposes (`git diff`) and for cherry-picking.)

Answer (score 1):

Another obvious approach is to do

```
git checkout -b master-again
git rebase -i --root
```

(it does not actually matter which branch you are in the beginning), and delete every commit in the opened editor, except the initial commit, which would be marked as `edit` and then replaced with the initial commit of the changed approach when the actual interactive rebase starts.

I think it would be possible to automate this to a single command by setting `GIT_EDITOR` to point to a suitable script.

I am looking for something even more straightforward, though, and something already existing.